# How to cycle through a array with images

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to know how to click a button and have the array automatically cycle through images at a certain speed per interval, and have the array cycle never end.
Please help me with this

I Have my original code where everytime the user clicks a button the image changes how do I get it so that it only requires one button click and the images constantly cycle.
Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```html
<img id="colour" src="C:/images/i1">
<button type="button" onclick="light_change()">Cycle Through</button>
<script>
  var assets = [
  "C:/images/i2",
  "C:/images/i3",
  "C:/images/i1"
  ]

  i = 0
  function light_cycle(){
    
  i = i+1
  if(i==assets.length)i=0
  var x =        document.getElementById('colour');
  x.src=assets[i]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you could add your code to the question, and have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: @Kenny or perhaps window.setInterval is more fitting for never ending cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will solve your problem

```
 function light_cycle(){
 window.setInterval(function() {
   i = i+1
   if(i==assets.length)i=0
   var x =        document.getElementById('colour');
   x.src=assets[i]
}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, helped loads

Comment: I hate to ask but would you mind explaining the code as I want to be able to fully understand it despite it being simple for you guys @Kenny

Comment: Just have a look at window.setInterval function...... It calls a function  at specified intervals (in milliseconds)..... I above case interval is 2000 milliseconds(2 seconds). So after every 2 seconds function written in it will be called

Answer (score 0):

in the comment place use images[imageNumber] as you wish.

```js
var images = ['imageA.jpg','imageB.jpg','imageC.jpg'];
var getButton = document.getElementById('but');
var getImgContainer = document.getElementById('imgContainer');
var slideTime = 2000;

getButton.onePush = false;

getButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  
  if(this.onePush) return;
  this.onePush = true;
  
  var imageNumber = 0;
  var newInterval = setInterval(function(){
    
    //do something with your urls HERE
    console.log(images[imageNumber]);
    getImgContainer.setAttribute('src',images[imageNumber]);
    
    if(imageNumber===images.length-1) {
      imageNumber = 0;
    } else {
      imageNumber++;
    }
  },slideTime);
  
});
```

```css
img {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px #33aaff;
}
```

```html
<button id="but">click me</button>
<br/><br/>
<img src="" id="imgContainer"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its really helped

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right what you want to get, so you need to move the i = i+1 to the end of the function like this :

```
function light_cycle(){
 window.setInterval(function() {
   if(i==assets.length)i=0
   var x =        document.getElementById('colour');
   x.src=assets[i]
   i = i+1
}, 3000);
}
```